# error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228

Tags: python

When I execute `supervisorctl reload`, an error appears:

```
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228
```

Answer (score 3):

Before executing `supervisorctl reload`, I needed to run the following command:

```
/data/service/jg/Python/bin/supervisord -c /data/service/jg/Python/supervisord.conf
```

Replace your paths (`/data/service/jg/Python/bin/` and `/data/service/jg/Python/`) accordingly!

Comment: I wanted to add a note that if you have installed supervisord via a yum or apt package on a Linux system, this simply means the installed service has not been started yet, so something as simple as `systemctl start supervisord` should do the trick!

Comment: exactly @OgrePsalm33!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `supervisord` is running properly.

```
systemctl start supervisord.service
```